# Wrong URL with simple_form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

i'm having issues generating a form for adding and editing existing users. It generates a wrong URL to submit. I have the following  models:

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :organization_users, :class_name => "::OrganizationUser", :foreign_key => :user_id, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :organizations, :through => :organization_users
```

Teacher:

```
class User::Teacher < User
```

Organization:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_many :organization_users
    has_many :users, :through => :organization_users
```

OrganizationUser:

```
class OrganizationUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, :class_name => "::User"
    belongs_to :organization
```

In my routes file i have created the next rules:

```
namespace :manager do
    resources :organizations, :only => [:edit, :update], :controller => "organizations/organizations" do
          resources :users, :only => [:index, :show, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy] do
  end
end
```

end

The user controller looks like this:

```
class Manager::UsersController < Manager::ApplicationController
      def new
        @user = user_scope.new
        respond_to do |format|
           format.html
        end
      end
      def edit
          respond_to do |format|
              format.html
          end
      end
```

And this is the form i have created:

```
= simple_form_for [:manager, @organization, @user], :as => :user, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal', :multipart => true} do |f|
    = f.input :type, :as => :hidden, :input_html => {:name => :type, :value => @type}
    %ul{:class=>%w(nav nav-tabs)}
    ......
```

With this form i can create new users without any problem. The problem is updating an existing one, getting this error:

```
undefined method `manager_organization_user_teacher_path'
```

I don't know why simple_form is generating the url with the type of the user (teacher), this path doesn't exist. How can I avoid this behaviour?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here i show how I load @user

UserController:

```
class Manager::UsersController < Manager::ApplicationController
    require_power_check

    power :crud => :users, :as => :user_scope

    before_filter :load_record, :only => [:show,:edit,:update,:destroy]

  def load_record
      @user = user_scope.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Here is my users scope power:

```
    power :users do
        types = []
        types << 'User::Teacher' if can_organization_teacher_index?
        types << 'User::Student' if can_organization_student_index?
        types << 'User::Parent' if can_organization_parent_index?
        User.active.where("type in      (?)",types).includes(:organization_users).where('organization_users.organization_id'=>@organization)
    end
```

I've tried MaximusDominus solution and it works but it would be nice to know why it's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your new action, `@user` is a `User`

In your edit action, `@user` is a `User::Teacher`

We need to see how you're loading up your @user resource to know why you're getting a User::Teacher instead of a User.

The easiest fix for this is the `becomes` method:

```
= simple_form_for [:manager, @organization, @user.becomes(User)], :as => :user...
```

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-becomes